# Permission Denied (publickey) during cap deploy ever since I moved to bitbucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ssh, capistrano, bitbucket

I've recently moved my git repo to bitbucket and now i'm unable to deploy my app because i'm getting this error:

```
 INFO [5a4fa711] Running /usr/bin/env git remote update on mysite.com
DEBUG [5a4fa711] Command: cd /var/www/mysite/repo && /usr/bin/env git remote update
DEBUG [5a4fa711]        Fetching origin
DEBUG [5a4fa711] 
DEBUG [5a4fa711]        Permission denied (publickey).
DEBUG [5a4fa711] 
DEBUG [5a4fa711]        fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
DEBUG [5a4fa711] 
DEBUG [5a4fa711]        error: Could not fetch origin
...
Tasks: TOP => git:create_release => git:update
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Command::Failed: git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Nothing written
```

I'm using capistrano 3 and here's the part that should forward my ssh options from my deploy file:

```
set :ssh_options, {
  user: fetch(:user),
  password: fetch(:password),
  keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa),
  forward_agent: true,
  auth_methods: %w(publickey password),
  port: 90
}
```

My public key from my local machine is on bitbucket already and this works:

```
$ ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
logged in as myuser.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `var/www/mysite/repo` folder on my server had some git references to my old repo (the non bitbucket one) so I just removed that folder. Voila!

Comment: I also Stuck!! on same kind of issue. But I didn't see any folder would you please tell me ..What could a problem ?